# MongoDB - Cast to ObjectId failed for value "create" at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

No matter what I try, I can't get rid of this error and I have several other features in my application that create instances of Mongoose Models which look almost exactly like this and they all work just fine.

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "create" at path "_id"
```

Any idea what would be throwing this error about the `_id`? I was under the impression that the `_id` value was automatically generated by Mongoose. I absolutely guarantee that there is no `id` or `_id` in my post data. It is only the `title` and `description` coming through.

This is my `Project` schema:

```
// Project Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

And this is my post route. I kept the code short for brevity.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Project = require('../models/project');

router.post('/project/create', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    };

    Project.create(data, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        if (!docs) {
            return res.send('Failed to create project');
        }

        res.send('Project created');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Finally, if I change from using the `create` method to the `save` method, I still get the same error.

```
var project = new Project(data);

project.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    res.send('Project created');
});
```

Comment: Probably just a typo, but are you requiring `Project`?

Comment: Oops, yes I forgot to include that in my code sample. Thanks for pointing that out @Hypermattt

Comment: Which version of `mongoose` are you using?

Comment: Mongoose is at v4.6.5

Comment: This is really odd… can you try console.logging (or inspecting) the value of `project._id` before calling `project.save()` in your second example?

Comment: @Hypermattt It's apparently failing within `new Project(data)` because if I include a `console` statement immediately after that, I still see the same error and the entire program terminates at that point. I agree this is very odd. It's baffling me because I've checked EVERYTHING, compared this against identical features, and have even re-typed it all just to be sure.

Comment: I've tested your code in a script (removing express entirely) and it works flawlessly… the issue must somehow be related to the express router setup.

Comment: …haha sorry to keep asking for versions, but which version of `expressjs` are you running? (also would be good to know the `nodejs` version)

Comment: Express is at v4.14.0 and Node is at v5.9.1

Comment: Are you parsing the request body?

Comment: Yes, here's my full list of dependencies lol.

"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-jwt": "^5.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.2",
    "express-validator": "^2.21.0",
    "moment": "^2.16.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.11",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.5",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  }

Answer (score 1):

I should have posted more of my code to help diagnosis this issue. It turns out my `/project/create` route was the issue.

I also had another route to view a project that was `/project/:id`. I supposed the `/create` part of my route was interfering with this logic so I changed the paths in my routes and all is working just fine now.

```
// Before
router.get('/projects', projects); // view all projects
router.get('/project/:id, project); // view a project
router.post('/project/:id', projectUpdate); // update a project
router.post('/project/create', projectCreate); // create a project
router.post('/project/delete/:id', projectDelete); // delete a project
```

My routes for this feature of my app now look like this:

```
// After
router.get('/projects', projects); // view all projects
router.get('/project/:id', project); // view a project
router.post('/project/', projectCreate); // create a project
router.post('/project/:id', projectUpdate); // update a project
router.post('/project/delete/:id', projectDelete); // delete a project
```

I learned a lesson today! Thanks for the help @Hypermattt.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that there is an error in some other part of your application, as the code pasted into the question seems to work flawlessly.

Here is some sample code I wrote in trying to debug your error. Try running it and see if it works on your local.

**`index.js`:**

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.connect( 'mongo' );

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  title: String,
  description: String
} );

const Project = mongoose.model( 'Project', ProjectSchema );

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const PORT = ( process.env.PORT || 1337 );
const express = require( 'express' );
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );
const router = express.Router();

router.post( '/project/create',
  bodyParser.json(),
  ( req, res ) => {
    console.log( 'request body:', req.body );

    const title = req.body.title;
    const description = req.body.description;

    Project.create( { title, description } )
    .then( doc => res.json( doc ) )
    .catch( err => res.json( err ) );
  }
);

app.use( router );
app.listen( PORT, () => console.log( `now listening on port ${PORT}` ) );
```

**`package.json`:**

```
{
  "name": "stack-overflow",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.11",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

**`docker-compose.yml`:**

```
mongo:
  image: 'mongo:3'
node:
  image: 'node:5.9.1'
  command: 'npm start'
  working_dir: '/var/app'
  links:
  - mongo
  volumes:
  - '.:/var/app'
  ports:
  - '1337:1337'
```

**example request:**

```
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:1337/project/create" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
 -d "{\"title\":\"testing\",\"description\":\"just another description\"}"
```